# validation startdate and enddate codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

i want to validate 2 date input in codeigniter, with the conditions, if the end date is greater than the start date, will appear warning [javascript warning or something] or data can't be input

my form like this,

```
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/kalender/buat" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
<?php
echo "<p><label for='IDKategori'>Tingkatan Pimpinan :</label><br/>";
echo form_dropdown('IDKategori', $kategori) . "</p>";

echo "<label for='ptitle'>Kegiatan / Lokasi :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'judul', 'id' => 'ptitle', 'size' => 80);
echo form_input($data);

echo "<p><label for='long'>Uraian Kegiatan / Keterangan / Catatan :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'konten', 'rows' => '13', 'cols' => '60', 'style' => 'width: 60%');
echo form_textarea($data) . "</p>";

echo "<p><label for='ptitle'>Waktu Mulai :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'TanggalMulai', 'id' => 'basic_example_1');
echo form_input($data) . "</p>";

echo "<p><label for='ptitle'>Waktu Akhir :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'TanggalAkhir', 'id' => 'basic_example_2');
echo form_input($data) . "</p>";

echo form_submit('submit', 'Tambah Even');
?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Kembali" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
```

and my javascript like this,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("TanggalAkhir", function(value, element) {
        var startDate = $('.TanggalMulai').val();
        return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value) || value == "";
    }, "* End date must be after start date");
    $('#form').validate();
});
```

why is not working ?

Comment: What date format are you using?

Comment: Nice I just spent 10 minutes answering a nearly duplicate question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the input as a class, but you haven't defined a class. Since you already defined an id, why not reference it that way:

```
var startDate = $('#basic_example_2').val();
```

Comment: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod("TanggalAkhir", function(value, element) {
            var startDate = $('#basic_example_1').val();
            return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value) || value == "";
        }, "End date must be after start date");
        $('#form').validate();
    });
</script>`