# issue validation startdate and enddate codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

i want to validate startdate and endate codeigniter, if stardate > enddate, not saving in my database, or show error message
my controller like this

```
function buat_lagi() {
    if ($this->input->post('IDKategori')) {
        $this->MKalender->addEvents();
        $id = $_POST[IDKategori];
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Agenda Pimpinan baru telah dibuat !');
        redirect('admin/kalenderkategori/lihat/' . $id . '', 'refresh');
    } else {
        $data['title'] = "Tambah Agenda Pimpinan";
        $data['kategori'] = $this->MKalenderKategori->getKategoriDropDown();
        $data['main'] = 'admin/kalender/kalender_buat_lagi';
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('layout/dashboard');
    }
}
```

my model like this

```
function addEvents() {
    $data = array(
        'IDKategori' => $this->input->post('IDKategori'),
        'TanggalMulai' => $this->input->post('TanggalMulai'),
        'TanggalAkhir' => $this->input->post('TanggalAkhir'),
        'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
        'konten' => $this->input->post('konten'),
        'create_by' => $_SESSION['username'],
    );
    $this->db->insert('kalender', $data);
}
```

my form like this

```
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/kalender/buat_lagi/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
<?php
echo "<label for='ptitle'>Kegiatan / Lokasi :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'judul', 'id' => 'ptitle', 'size' => 80);
echo form_input($data);

echo "<p><label for='long'>Uraian Kegiatan / Keterangan / Catatan :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'konten', 'rows' => '13', 'cols' => '60', 'style' => 'width: 60%');
echo form_textarea($data) . "</p>";

echo "<p><label for='ptitle'>Waktu Mulai :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'TanggalMulai', 'id' => 'basic_example_1');
echo form_input($data) . "</p>";

echo "<p><label for='ptitle'>Waktu Akhir :</label><br/>";
$data = array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input', 'name' => 'TanggalAkhir', 'id' => 'basic_example_2', 'onblur' => 'function compareDate()');
echo form_input($data) . "</p>";

echo form_hidden('IDKategori', $this->uri->segment(4));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Tambah Even');
?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Kembali" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
```

how to validate my issue ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [validation startdate and enddate codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546690/validation-startdate-and-enddate-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given the format of your dates or even which the date fields are (keep in mind most of the users here speak primarily English) You also haven't stated if you want this check server side or client side. By the compare dates function called in your form I am assuming you want it at least client side, I would suggest though that form validation needs to be done server side as well. Client side is great for immediate notification to the user but it's useless for actually protecting input to the form server side.

jQuery for the client side (since I am not sure which field is which this is pseudo code:

```
function compareDate()
    {
var startDate = Date.parse($("#startDate).val()");
var endDate = Date.parse($("#endDate).val()");
if(startDate>endDate)
{
alert("Your start date must be earlier than your end date.");
}
    }
```

Codeigniter function (the callback should work but I haven't tested it.) You really only have to run the function on one of the date fields, you only want to return one error and it's irrelevant which you return it on since it's comparing the two.

```
//validation rule
$this->form_validtion->set_rules('endDate', 'End Date','trim|callback_compareDates');


function compareDates()
{
$start = strtotime($this->input->post('startDate'));
$end = strtotime($this->input->post('endDate'));
if($start > $end)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('compareDates','Your start date must be earlier than your end date');
    return false;
}
```